# when i Click an item on Expandable listview the move to the next activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview

all i want to happen is when i click one item in my Expandable Listview it's show a new activity.
for example i have a list of names(paul,john,mark,james,luke) in my Expandable Listview and when i click #james the new activity well open contains information about #james.

```
/*********************************CategoryScreen.java*************/

package filipiknows.open;

import filipiknows.open.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener;

public class CategoryScreen extends Activity {

    ELAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.category);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ELAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // Listview Group click listener
        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });


        // Listview on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });
    }


    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Phillippines Heroes");
        listDataHeader.add("Presidents");
        listDataHeader.add("Culture and Tradition");
        listDataHeader.add("Tourist Spots");
        listDataHeader.add("Filipino Dishes");
        listDataHeader.add("Traditional Customes");
        listDataHeader.add("Traditional Games");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> PhillippinesHeroes = new ArrayList<String>();
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Dr. Jose Rizal");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Andres Bonifacio");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("General Gregorio del Pilar");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("General Emilio Aguinaldo");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Apolinario Mabini");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Father Mariano Gomez");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Father Father Jose Burgos ");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Father Father Jacinto Zamora");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Trece Martirez");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Emilio Jacinto");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("General Antonio Luna");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Melchora Aquino");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Graciano Lopez-Jaena");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Panday Pira");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Mariano Ponce");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Gregoria de Jesus");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Fernando Ma. Guerrero");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Felipe Agoncillo");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Juan Luna");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Rafael Palma");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Marcelo H. Del Pilar");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Pedro Paterno");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Leona Florentino");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Isabelo delos Reyes");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Artemio Ricarte");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Jose Palma");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Rajah Lakandola");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Rajah Soliman");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Leonor Rivera");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Marcela Mariño Agoncillo");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Galicano Apacible");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Jose Ma. Panganiban");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Diego Silang");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Maria Josefa Gabriela Silang");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Lapu-Lapu");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Francisco Baltazar");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Epifanio delos Santos");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Francisco Dagohoy");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Teresa Magbanua");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Trinidad Tecson");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Agueda Esteban");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Julian Felipe");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("Marina Dizon");
        PhillippinesHeroes.add("General Francisco Makabulos");

        List<String> Presidents = new ArrayList<String>();
        Presidents.add("Emilio Aguinaldo");
        Presidents.add("Manuel L. Quezon");
        Presidents.add("José P. Laurel");
        Presidents.add("Sergio S. Osmeña");
        Presidents.add("Manuel A. Roxas");
        Presidents.add("Elpidio R. Quirino");
        Presidents.add("Ramón F. Magsaysay");
        Presidents.add("Carlos P. García");
        Presidents.add("Diosdado P. Macapagal");
        Presidents.add("Ferdinand E. Marcos");
        Presidents.add("Corazón C. Aquino");
        Presidents.add("Fidel V. Ramos");
        Presidents.add("Joseph Ejército Estrada");
        Presidents.add("Gloria Macapagal Arroyo");
        Presidents.add("Benigno S. Aquino III");

        List<String> CultureAndTradition = new ArrayList<String>();
        CultureAndTradition.add("");
        CultureAndTradition.add("");
        CultureAndTradition.add("");
        CultureAndTradition.add("");
        CultureAndTradition.add("");
        CultureAndTradition.add("");

        List<String> TouristSpots = new ArrayList<String>();
        TouristSpots.add("Manila");
        TouristSpots.add("Bohol");
        TouristSpots.add("Boracay");
        TouristSpots.add("baguio");
        TouristSpots.add("Cagayan");
        TouristSpots.add("Cagayan De Oro");
        TouristSpots.add("Camiguin");
        TouristSpots.add("Cebu");
        TouristSpots.add("Davao City");
        TouristSpots.add("Ilocos Norte");
        TouristSpots.add("Negros Oriental");
        TouristSpots.add("Puerto Prencesa");
        TouristSpots.add("Zambales");

        List<String> FilipinoDishes = new ArrayList<String>();
        FilipinoDishes.add("Adobo");
        FilipinoDishes.add("Balut");
        FilipinoDishes.add("Lechon");
        FilipinoDishes.add("Sisig");
        FilipinoDishes.add("Crispy Pata");
        FilipinoDishes.add("Chicken Inasal");
        FilipinoDishes.add("Pansit Palabok");
        FilipinoDishes.add("Bulalo");
        FilipinoDishes.add("Arroz Caldo");
        FilipinoDishes.add("Kare-Kare");
        FilipinoDishes.add("Sinigang");
        FilipinoDishes.add("Dinuguan at puto");
        FilipinoDishes.add("Laing");
        FilipinoDishes.add("Pinakbet");
        FilipinoDishes.add("Bicol Express");
        FilipinoDishes.add("Tinola");
        FilipinoDishes.add("Halo-Halo");
        FilipinoDishes.add("Taho");
        FilipinoDishes.add("Turon");
        FilipinoDishes.add("Longaniza");
        FilipinoDishes.add("Lumpiang Sariwa");

        List<String> TraditionalCustomes = new ArrayList<String>();
        TraditionalCustomes.add("Barong Tagalog");
        TraditionalCustomes.add("Mestiza");
        TraditionalCustomes.add("Maria Clara");
        TraditionalCustomes.add("Kimona");
        TraditionalCustomes.add("Igorot");
        TraditionalCustomes.add("Muslim Attire");
        TraditionalCustomes.add("Malong");
        TraditionalCustomes.add("B’LAAN");
        TraditionalCustomes.add("Bagobo")
        TraditionalCustomes.add("T’BOLI");
        TraditionalCustomes.add("Mandaya");
        TraditionalCustomes.add("Maranaw");
        TraditionalCustomes.add("Yakan");
        TraditionalCustomes.add("Ifugao");
        TraditionalCustomes.add("Kalinga");
        TraditionalCustomes.add("GA’DANG");
        TraditionalCustomes.add("Bontoc");
        TraditionalCustomes.add("Samal");
        TraditionalCustomes.add("Ibaloi");
        TraditionalCustomes.add("Aetas");
        TraditionalCustomes.add("Pulangiyen");
        TraditionalCustomes.add("Matigsalug");

        List<String> TraditionalGames = new ArrayList<String>();
        TraditionalGames.add("Tumbang Preso");
        TraditionalGames.add("Luksong-Baka");
        TraditionalGames.add("Luksong-tinik");
        TraditionalGames.add("Piko");
        TraditionalGames.add("Agawan Base");
        TraditionalGames.add("Bahay-Bahayan");
        TraditionalGames.add("Chinese Garter");
        TraditionalGames.add("Holen");
        TraditionalGames.add("Jack 'n' Poy");
        TraditionalGames.add("Langit-Lupa");
        TraditionalGames.add("Pitik-Bulag");
        TraditionalGames.add("Sawsaw-Suka");
        TraditionalGames.add("Sipa");
        TraditionalGames.add("Taguan");
        TraditionalGames.add("Takip-Silim");
        TraditionalGames.add("Ten-Twenty");
        TraditionalGames.add("Tinikling");
        TraditionalGames.add("Ubusan Lahi");
        TraditionalGames.add("Teks");

        // Header at Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), PhillippinesHeroes); 
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), Presidents);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), CultureAndTradition);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), TouristSpots);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), FilipinoDishes);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(5), TraditionalCustomes);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(6), TraditionalGames);
    }
}
```

/************Extended Listview Adapter(ELAdapter.java)*********************************************/

```
package filipiknows.open;

import filipiknows.open.R;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ELAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ELAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: And what is happening now when you click the item?

Comment: well you have attached a childClickListener, but you didnt fill it with anything useful. you will have to start the activity in the click listener, and pass along all necessary data to either display the full information you mean to display, or enough information to pull data from db/whatever

Comment: What Daniel said is correct, also why not use a Fragment to load the information into ?

Comment: @joao2fast4u when i click item they move to new activity that contain an information about this *item..

Comment: @IslandWave yah you right i want to use a Fragment but i don't have an idea how to insert Fragment in expandable list... sorry guys i'm just a newbie in android programming

Comment: @DanielBo thank you sir for your comment.. can i have a favor can you give an sample code guys. again thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

As im not entirely sure what it is that you are trying to to do, this is how id start an activity with a textview in it, that shows the clicked persons text.

Implementation of ClickListener

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("Name", listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosititon));
    startActivity(i);
    return true;
}
```

Simple Activity to show text

```
public class DetailsActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv;

    public View onCreate(SavedInstanceState bundle) {
        tv = new TextView(this);

        return tv;
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        tv.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Name", "SomeDefaultValue"));
    }

}
```

this should show how to do it, if you cant adapt that to your need, you might want to look at a tutorial :)